# Accessing Spring managed beans outside spring managed classes in kotlin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

We can access spring managed beans from a class which is not spring managed by using the getBean method of below function. I want to do same but in Kotlin. How can I re-write getBeans function in kotlin to make it work?

```
@Component
public class SpringContext implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext context;

    /**
     * Returns the Spring managed bean instance of the given class type if it exists.
     * Returns null otherwise.
     * @param beanClass
     * @return
     */

    public static <T extends Object> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
        return context.getBean(beanClass);
    }


    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {

        // store ApplicationContext reference to access required beans later on
        SpringContext.context = context;
    }
}
```

I tried to convert it in kotlin but i am getting error.

```
@Component
class SpringContext : ApplicationContextAware {
    @Throws(BeansException::class)
    override fun setApplicationContext(context: ApplicationContext) {
        // store ApplicationContext reference to access required beans later on
        SpringContext.Companion.context = context
    }

    companion object {
        private var context: ApplicationContext? = null

        fun <T : Any>getBean(beanClass: KClass<out T>): Any {
            return context!!.getBean(beanClass)
        }
    }
}
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Object' available: more than one 'primary' bean found among candidates: [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor, org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor, org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor, org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor, org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor, org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory....]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.determinePrimaryCandidate(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:350)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1133)
```

Somehow the beanClass variable is getting java.lang.Object. Why this is happening and how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

My Kotlin application has a Spring Bean created of the class called `WhiskyCrawler`.
 I have the Spring context only in my `main` method, so I can call `getBean` only there. 
But since you have the Spring context in your code, you can focus on the last line in the following code snippet:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    class WhiskyApplication

    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val context = runApplication<WhiskyApplication>(*args)
        val crawler = context.getBean(WhiskyCrawler::class.java)
```