# Run script @Bean classes in kotlin spring application

Tags: spring, kotlin

So I have a spring application on kotlin and to test a particular class I want to write up a script but the problem is all these classes are @Component and it'll be pain to intialize each class using `new` . Is there any way I can utilise the Beans configured in my `main function`.

I've tried setting up applciation context which returns null, tried lot of things from internet but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some searching. I found a way.

in the main function where the Spring application starts.

```
    val context = runApplication<App>(*args)
    val crawler = context.getBean(MyClass::class.java)
```

ref: [Accessing Spring managed beans outside spring managed classes in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68971862/accessing-spring-managed-beans-outside-spring-managed-classes-in-kotlin)